# why my grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows don't work?

Tags: grid

[this is my render on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXYYS.png) why grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows work weirdly what i'm missing ?

i had placed grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows with the display: grid;  but it doesn't work.....

```
html:
 <div class="parent" > 
       <div class="box box1">box1</div>
       <div class="box box2">box2</div>
       <div class="box box3">box3</div>  <div class="box box4">box4<div>
       <div class="box box5">box5</div> 
       <div class="box box6">box6</div>
       <div class="box box7">box7</div>  <div class="box box8">box8<div>
       <div class="box box9">box9</div>
   </div>


css:

.parent{
    background-color: rgb(106, 110, 102);
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 50% 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px ;
}

.box{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(190, 190, 6);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two divs that are sticking out are missing closing div tags

`<div class="box box4">box4<div>`

Comment: omg i'm so stupide , how i could miss that , thank you man you're a life saver

Comment: No problem, to be fair it took me a minute, its always the simple ones that get you :)